# Opening programmatically a TopComponent

Tags: java, netbeans

I am opening a TopComponent for a DataObject with this code after performing an action:

```
TopComponent tc = MultiViews.createMultiView("text/experiment+xml", expDO);
tc.open();
tc.requestActive();
```

This works fine, but if I double click in the node of the DataObject, a new TopComponent is opened even though a TopComponent is just opened for it.

However, if I only open a TopComponent with double click, always one and unique TopComponent is opened for the DataObject.

This behaviour only happens when I open a TopComponent with the code above.
I suspect that the TopComponent is not registered in the TopComponent.registry, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Edit:
This is the DataObject implementation (I've avoided the annotations that register mime-type and Action's ):

```
public class ExperimentDataObject extends MultiDataObject implements PropertyChangeListener {

private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
private Lookup lookup;
private InstanceContent ic = new InstanceContent();

private final Project project;
private final Experiment experiment;

public ExperimentDataObject(FileObject expFO, MultiFileLoader loader) throws DataObjectExistsException, IOException {
    super(expFO, loader);
    registerEditor("text/experiment+xml", true); 

    this.project = FileOwnerQuery.getOwner( expFO ); 
    this.experiment = getObject(); 

    this.experiment.setConfigFile(expFO);

    experiment.addPropertyChangeListener(this);

    expFO.setAttribute(AwsItem.ITEM_TYPE, AwsItemType.EXPERIMENT);
    expFO.setAttribute(AwsItem.PROP_PROJECT, this.project); 

    LOGGER.trace("ExperimentDataObject " + this.getName() + " created.");
}

@Override
protected int associateLookup() {
    return 1;
}


private class MyOpenCookie implements OpenCookie {
    public void open(){
        TopComponent tc = MultiViews.createMultiView("text/experiment+xml", ExperimentDataObject.this);
        tc.open();
        tc.requestActive();
    }
}

/**
 * Lookup implementation. 
 * @return 
 */
@Override
public Lookup getLookup() {

    if (lookup == null) {
        lookup = new AbstractLookup(ic);
        ic.add(this);
        ic.add(project);
        ic.add(experiment);
        ic.add(new MyOpenCookie());
    }

    LOGGER.trace("ExperimentDO.getLookup() called.");

    return lookup;
}

/**
 * Creates the ExperimentDataNode for this DataObject
 * @return 
 */
@Override
protected Node createNodeDelegate() {
    return new ExperimentDataNode(this);
}

/**
 * Generates the experiment java object.<br>
 * It must be created when the DataObject is constructed, in this way, the instance object is in 
 * the lookup of the DataObject.
 * 
 * @return Experiment instance object
 */
private Experiment getObject() throws IOException {

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new PureJavaReflectionProvider());
    xstream.processAnnotations(Experiment.class);

    return (Experiment) xstream.fromXML(FileUtil.toFile(this.getPrimaryFile()));
}

/**
 * Saves the experiment java object to the config FileObject.<br>Doesn't matter if the experiment object has charged dataConfig in its DataItem's, because the object Experiment.ChannelData.dataItems is transient and they are not serialized.
 */
public void saveConfig() throws IOException {

    FileLock doFileLock = this.getPrimaryFile().lock();

    String xmlStr;
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(Experiment.class);
    xmlStr = xstream.toXML(experiment);

    byte[] bytes = xmlStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    OutputStream os = this.getPrimaryFile().getOutputStream(doFileLock);
    os.write(bytes);
    os.flush();

    os.close();
    doFileLock.releaseLock();
    os = null;
}

/**
 * Detects change events in the the AwsItem object.<br>
```

Properties changes can be fired from AwsItem or from the ChannelData objects of the AwsItem
     * 
     * @param evt 
     */
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

```
    if (evt.getPropertyName() == AwsItem.PROP_CONFIG) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        saveConfig();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        LOGGER.warn("Problem saving changes in AwsItem.", ex);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
}
```

And this is the DataNode code:
    public class ExperimentDataNode extends DataNode {

```
public static final String EXPERIMENT_NODE_ICON = "com/aws/experiment/resources/experiment.png";
private final ExperimentDataObject expDO;

private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());


public ExperimentDataNode(ExperimentDataObject expDO) {
    super(expDO, Children.LEAF);
    this.expDO = expDO;
}

@Override
public Action[] getActions(boolean context) {
    return new Action[]{
        SystemAction.get(OpenAction.class),
        SystemAction.get(RenameAction.class),
        SystemAction.get(DeleteAction.class),
    };
}

public String getHtmlDisplayName() {

    String result = this.getDataObject().getName();

    if (result != null) return result;
    else return "Experiment"; 
}

@Override
public boolean canRename() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Renames the DataNode and the DataObject.<br>
 * Also renames the object Experiment that DataObject represents.
 * @param name
 * @param renameDO 
 */
@Override
public void setName(String name, boolean renameDO) {

    super.setName(name, true);

    Experiment exp = this.expDO.getLookup().lookup(Experiment.class);
    exp.setName(name);
}

@Override
public boolean canDestroy() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Deletes the DataObject and the data file associated to it.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
@Override
public void destroy() throws IOException {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Mode editorMode = WindowManager.getDefault().findMode("editor");
            TopComponent[] openTopComponentsInEditorMode = editorMode.getTopComponents();

            for (TopComponent tc : openTopComponentsInEditorMode) {

                if ( tc.getLookup().lookup(DataObject.class) == expDO) {
                    tc.close();
                }
            }

            try {
                Experiment experiment = expDO.getLookup().lookup(Experiment.class);
                experiment.deleteChannelData(); 
                expDO.delete();
                fireNodeDestroyed();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("Problem deleting item experiment.", ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import org.openide.cookies.EditorCookie;

EditorCookie ec = expDO.getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.class);
ec.openDocument();

OR

import org.openide.cookies.OpenCookie;

OpenCookie ec = expDO.getLookup().lookup(OpenCookie.class);
ec.open();

If OpenCookie is null, then in your DataObject, add the missing Cookie using one of the below methods.

```
public class MyMultiDataObject extends MultiDataObject {

    public MyMultiDataObject(FileObject fileObj, DataLoader loader)
            throws DataObjectExistsException {
        super(fileObj, loader);
        getCookieSet().add(new MyOpenCookie());
    }

    private class MyOpenCookie implements OpenCookie {
        public void open(){
            //Open your desired TopCompnent; Call your current double click action that has the desired behavior
        }
    }
}
```

OR better yet, simply call the MultiDataObject.regiserEditor(...) method in your constructor;

```
public class MyMultiDataObject extends MultiDataObject {

    public MyMultiDataObject(FileObject fileObj, DataLoader loader)
            throws DataObjectExistsException {
        super(fileObj, loader);
        registerEditor("text/experiment+xml", true);
    }
}
```

Taken from MultiDataObject

```
   /** Utility method to register editor for this {@link DataObject}.
     * Call it from constructor with appropriate mimeType. The system will
     * make sure that appropriate cookies ({@link Openable}, {@link Editable},
     * {@link CloseCookie}, {@link EditorCookie}, {@link SaveAsCapable},
     * {@link LineCookie} are registered into {@link #getCookieSet()}.
     * <p>
     * The selected editor is <a href="@org-netbeans-core-multiview@/org/netbeans/core/api/multiview/MultiViews.html">
     * MultiView component</a>, if requested (this requires presence of
     * the <a href="@org-netbeans-core-multiview@/overview-summary.html">MultiView API</a>
     * in the system. Otherwise it is plain {@link CloneableEditor}.
     * 
     * @param mimeType mime type to associate with
     * @param useMultiview should the used component be multiview?
     * @since 7.27
     */
    protected final void registerEditor(final String mimeType, boolean useMultiview) {
        MultiDOEditor.registerEditor(this, mimeType, useMultiview);
    }
```

Comment: Don't create your own multi-view, but instead have the DataObject's OpenCookie open the TopComponent for you. This is what is performed when you double click on the DataNode.

Comment: But this method implies implements in the DataObject some interface or abstract class like OpenSupport or OpenCookie, isn't it? Actually my DataObject class extends MultiDataObject and I don't need to implement nothing to open support to open when double clicking. If I'll do as you suggest, I'll need to implement the open() method. How can I put an abstract OpenCookie or OpenSupport?

Comment: If you can already double-click open on the DataNode, or right-click 'Open'. Then the OpenCookie.class or Openable.class is aready in the Lookup. The above code will work.

Comment: Nop, always returns null object when I search in DataObject's lookup. I've tried with EditorCookie, OpenCookie, Openable, OpenSupport....and nothing.

Comment: Your MultiDataObject registers the OpenCookie either via a call to 'registerEditor("mimeName", true)' in the constructor OR you can also add  your own cookies by calling getCookieSet().add(new YourOpenCookieHere()) in the constructor.

Comment: I just call registerEditor("mimeName", true) in the DataObject's constructor. Anyway, I've implemented the inner class MyOpenCookie and puts in the DataObject's Lookup in. Then in the Action where I need to open programatically the TopComponent, I call `OpenCookie ec = ((ExperimentDataObject)expDO).getLookup().lookup(OpenCookie.class);
            ec.open();` and the result is the same: the new TopComponent is opened, but if I double click in the DataNode, the TopComponent is opened twice.

Comment: Need to you to paste your custom DataObject code so we can see what is going on. What action is set as the default double-click action? If your OpenCookie.class is executing the exact same action then you shouldn't get a different behavior.

Comment: Also attach/paste the code of the Node you are using if you Overrode the createNodeDelegate() method in your DataObject class. This should allow us to see if you Overrode the getPreffedAction() or getDefaultAction() which is being executed when you double-click.

Comment: The code attached has the OpenCookie implementation and addition to the lookup, the last I've tried, but in the original code I only call `registerEditor("text/experiment+xml", true);`

Comment: The registerEditor("text/experiment+xml...) should be enough, so remove the MyOpenCookie class from your DataObject. The issue is likely in the overriding of getLookup() in your DataObject i.e. the cookies added by regisetEditor(...) are not included in your InstanceContext. Try replacing 'lookup = new AbstractLookup(ic); with lookup = new ProxyLookup(new AbstractLookup(ic), super.getLookup()); Then to grammatically open the TopComponent use ' expDO.getLookup().lookup(OpenCookie.class).open()'

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!!! And I resolve another collateral problems I had in the lookup of the DataNodes. Thanks very much for your help.